# how to find the document in mongodb database which contain multiple collections in a schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my MongoDB schema.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        username     :String,
        name         : String,
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    },
    twitter          : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        displayName  : String,
        username     : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }

});
```

I want to find the document which contains username which I specify in the argument and to achieve it I write below line of code

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
   var u = new User();

    var query = {u.local.username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}
```

but it says unexpected token.What should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` needs to provide the name of the field to match against using a dot-notation string:

```
var query = {'local.username': username};
```